# Static variables are getting initialized again when ever function gets called - Java

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I want to have the userScore and computerScore updated every time the user inputs 'y' to play again, but instead, the scores get initialized from 0.
I have made an ArrayList to show the results every time user plays. Does Anyone have any suggestion on a better implementation for this?
Please ignore violation of the DRY principal :)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class OddsAndEvens{
  static int UserScore = 0;
  static int computerScore = 0;
  static ArrayList<Integer> UserScoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static ArrayList<Integer> computerScoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void main(String args[]){
    BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = "", choice="";

    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Let's play a game called Odds and Evens");

    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    try{
      name = console.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error while name input: " + e);
    }

    System.out.print("Hi " + name + ", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? ");
    try{
      choice = console.readLine().toLowerCase();
    } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error while Choosing Odd or Even: " + e);
    }

    if(choice.startsWith("o")){
      System.out.println(name + " chose ODDS, the Computer will be EVENS");
    } else if(choice.startsWith("e")){
      System.out.println(name + " chose EVENS, the Computer will be ODDS");
    } else{
      System.out.println("Enter a valid choice "+ name + "..Either O(o) or E(e)");
    }

    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println();

    while(play(console, name, choice, UserScore, computerScore).startsWith("y")){
      play(console, name, choice, UserScore, computerScore);
    }

  }

  public static String play(BufferedReader console, String name, String choice, int UserScore, int computerScore){
    int numberOfFingers = 0;

    UserScoreArray.add(0);
    computerScoreArray.add(0);

    System.out.println("How many 'fingers' do you put out?(You can only put out 5 fingers)");
    try{
      numberOfFingers = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
    } catch(Exception e1){
      System.out.println("Error while, taking number of fingers: " + e1);
    }
    if(numberOfFingers > 5){
      System.out.println("You cannot put out more than 5 fingers " + name);
      System.out.println("Let's try again!");
      play(console, name, choice, UserScore, computerScore);
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int computerFingers = rand.nextInt(6);

    System.out.println("The computer played: " + computerFingers);

    int sum = numberOfFingers + computerFingers;
    System.out.println("sum = " + numberOfFingers  + "+" + computerFingers);

    if(sum%2 == 0){
      System.out.println(sum + " is. . . . Even");
      if(choice.startsWith("e")){
        System.out.println("The Winner is " + name);
        UserScore++;
        UserScoreArray.add(UserScore);
        System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
      } else{
        System.out.println("The Winner is Computer");
        computerScore++;
        computerScoreArray.add(computerScore);
        System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
      }
    } else{
        System.out.println(sum + " is. . . . Odd");
        if(choice.startsWith("o")){
          System.out.println("The Winner is " + name);
          UserScore++;
          UserScoreArray.add(UserScore);
          System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
          System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
        } else{
          System.out.println("The Winner is Computer");
          computerScore++;
          computerScoreArray.add(computerScore);
          System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
          System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println(name + "'s Array List contents: " + "\n" + UserScoreArray);
    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println("Computer's Array List contents: " + "\n" + computerScoreArray);
    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("How does the Score look like " + name + ", Want to Play again?(y or n)");

    String playAgain = "";

    try{
      playAgain = console.readLine().toLowerCase();
    } catch(Exception e3){
      System.out.println("Error in function for playAgain: " + e3);
    }

    if(playAgain.startsWith("y")){
      System.out.println("Starting another game-");
      return playAgain;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Thank you for playing, see you soon..");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    return "p";
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Aditya! Welcome to SO and please, take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It will help you move around better. I'd also recommend Essentials lesson from Oracle Java Trails, may be helpful in further endeavors. Good luck!

Comment: As Little Ancient Forest Kami says, welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted a lot of code here - well over 100 lines. It would be helpful if you could reduce this to a [mcve]. It's great that you've already provided *complete* code, but it would be better if it were *minimal*. I suspect you can demonstrate the problem in under 50 lines of code (maybe under 30...), which would make this a much better question for Stack Overflow, and more likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , it will works, you need to intialies `index 0` of 2 arrays in the beginining of `main` method

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

class OddsAndEvens{
  static int UserScore = 0;
  static int computerScore = 0;
  static ArrayList<Integer> UserScoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  static ArrayList<Integer> computerScoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public static void main(String args[]){
      UserScoreArray.add(0);
        computerScoreArray.add(0);

  BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = "", choice="";

    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Let's play a game called Odds and Evens");

    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    try{
      name = console.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error while name input: " + e);
    }

    System.out.print("Hi " + name + ", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? ");
    try{
      choice = console.readLine().toLowerCase();
    } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error while Choosing Odd or Even: " + e);
    }

    if(choice.startsWith("o")){
      System.out.println(name + " chose ODDS, the Computer will be EVENS");
    } else if(choice.startsWith("e")){
      System.out.println(name + " chose EVENS, the Computer will be ODDS");
    } else{
      System.out.println("Enter a valid choice "+ name + "..Either O(o) or E(e)");
    }

    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println();

    while(play(console, name, choice, UserScore, computerScore).startsWith("y")){
      play(console, name, choice, UserScore, computerScore);
    }

  }

  public static String play(BufferedReader console, String name, String choice, int UserScore, int computerScore){
    int numberOfFingers = 0;


    System.out.println("How many 'fingers' do you put out?(You can only put out 5 fingers)");
    try{
      numberOfFingers = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
    } catch(Exception e1){
      System.out.println("Error while, taking number of fingers: " + e1);
    }
    if(numberOfFingers > 5){
      System.out.println("You cannot put out more than 5 fingers " + name);
      System.out.println("Let's try again!");
      play(console, name, choice, UserScore, computerScore);
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int computerFingers = rand.nextInt(6);

    System.out.println("The computer played: " + computerFingers);

    int sum = numberOfFingers + computerFingers;
    System.out.println("sum = " + numberOfFingers  + "+" + computerFingers);

    if(sum%2 == 0){
      System.out.println(sum + " is. . . . Even");
      if(choice.startsWith("e")){
        System.out.println("The Winner is " + name);
        UserScore++;
        UserScoreArray.add(UserScore + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
        System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
      } else{
        System.out.println("The Winner is Computer");
        computerScore++;
        computerScoreArray.add(computerScore + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
        System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
      }
    } else{
        System.out.println(sum + " is. . . . Odd");
        if(choice.startsWith("o")){
          System.out.println("The Winner is " + name);
          UserScore++;
          UserScoreArray.add(UserScore  + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
          System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
          System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
        } else{
          System.out.println("The Winner is Computer");
          computerScore++;
          computerScoreArray.add(computerScore + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
          System.out.println(name + "'s score: " + UserScoreArray.get(UserScoreArray.size() - 1));
          System.out.println("Computer's score: " + computerScoreArray.get(computerScoreArray.size() - 1));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println(name + "'s Array List contents: " + "\n" + UserScoreArray);
    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println("Computer's Array List contents: " + "\n" + computerScoreArray);
    System.out.println("______________________________________________________________________________");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("How does the Score look like " + name + ", Want to Play again?(y or n)");

    String playAgain = "";

    try{
      playAgain = console.readLine().toLowerCase();
    } catch(Exception e3){
      System.out.println("Error in function for playAgain: " + e3);
    }

    if(playAgain.startsWith("y")){
      System.out.println("Starting another game-");
      return playAgain;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Thank you for playing, see you soon..");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    return "p";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please note that static variable is seen in all instances of a class. You don't need to pass it as a parameter to a method.
2. If you pass it as a parameter, please note the parameter name. If your variable is called "score" and your parameter is called "score" as well, what you are changing (with "score++" or other "score" manipulation) is no longer the "score" class variable, but a method parameter, and changes done to it will no longer be visible when you exit the method. This is called shadowing.

I suggest (for similar questions) a sister-site to SO - one that deals with code reviews. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You may learn more there, since here we tend to focus on specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your method parameters.You have two unwanted
method parameters in your play method.just remove `UserScore` &
`computerScore` parameters from your play method and your code should work well.

In your class, `UserScore` & `computerScore` fields are static. so no
need to pass those field values to another static method within the
same class.In your code those parameters just hide the actual static
fields.when you print the value of `UserScore` or `computerScore` in play
method, java just print the value of the local method parameters
instead of static fields.